# Can't connect to internet with tp link wn8200nd adapter

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, tp-link

I recently installed Ubuntu as a second operating system on my pc and I am having trouble connecting to the internet. I use a tp-link wn8200nd wifi adapter and it works perfect with windows 10 When I boot in Ubuntu and I try to connect I see the available networks, I enter the password and after some time it says connection failed. I have tried both versions 18.04 and 18.10 but the problem remains. I've seen a lot of solutions like disabling random mac and installing new drivers but it didn't work. I also tried connecting to a different network via mobile hotspot but same thing happened.  As of now I don't have an ethernet cable long enough to connect it so I use my phone with bluetooth tethering. Has anybody had the same problem or knows how to solve it?
I'd be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: So you cannot connect via phone and Ubuntu to this network?

Comment: My phone, windows 10 and other devices connect fine to the network. I tried connecting with hotspot to see if it was specific to the nework but it didn't connet to hotspot either.

Comment: what is the output for `ip a` ?

Comment: I get this after `ip a` https://pastebin.com/6r8VUH8J

Comment: State is DOWN you have to set it UP `sudo ifup enp6s0` alternatively if it don't work bring all up `sudo ifup -a`

Comment: I tried both. `sudo ifup enp6s0` returns: Unknown interface enp6s0 and `sudo ifup -a` returns nothing. The problem remains.